# How SVN work with large files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i m working on UDK. The size of each map in UDK is around **200MB+**.

I had upload them to my SVN server.. But now i wants to commit those maps.

**My Question is**
Whether my svn client upload those all maps again (200+MB again) or just changes on those maps(approx 15+MB).?

I read on this forum, but don't think, this'll also apply on large files.
http://fluxbb.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=21182#p21182

Also Is it efficient to store large files in SVN, becoz if any set of data in a single file lost, then the whole file will be corrupt.

I am using **TortoiseSVN** Client

Thankx

Answer (score 2):

If the content in your files in in text format and multiple lines then only the changed lines will be uploaded. That is efficient.

If it is a binary file, you have no benefit in using SVN since it is keeping copies of the whole file at commit.

Comment: Then Is there any other solution to backup those files except manual backup of all files.?

Comment: If you are using SVN for backups you are not using it for its intended purpose. SVN is a Version Control system, not a backup system, or file sever, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to commit a rar ball about 8 MB to my svn server, then add a small file to the rar ball, in my second commit I'm sure it just upload the changes, not the whole file.

So, although it is a binary file, TortoiseSVN can only upload the 15 MB changes, not ur whole 200 MB file.

Comment: But @Cheburashk, i read in a thread that SVN works on chunk of data i.e., it compare each line in old file with new file & write this.